# How to change the Date Format '27JAN2017 to 27JA2017' in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am working `WPF` application using `C#` and `.Net Framework 4.0`. I want to change the format of the date and display in my application screen. Currently I am displaying the date in this format - `mm/dd/yyyy` that is `(01/27/2017)`. I want to change the format from `"01/27/2017"` to `"26JA2017"`.

I tried the below code,

```
value = Convert.ToDateTime(currentDate).ToString("ddMMMyyyy");
```

The above code is changing the date from `"01/27/2017"` to `"27JAN2017"`. I want it to be `27JA2017`. The customer is from France and he need the date format to be in French.

Can anyone of you help me in converting the date format from `"27JAN2017"` to `"27JA2017"`?

Comment: How would 1st March vs 1st May look? Would they both be `01MA2017`? Same for June/July? Is the `JA` from `Janvier` or `January`? Would April be `AP` or `AV`?

Comment: Indeed - basically this is a really bad idea due to ambiguity. That's why there's no support for it in the framework...

Comment: That's not a French format. That's just some system's custom format. You'll have to create a lookup array - just create a 12 element array with the names and use `[date.Month-1]` as the index to it

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country) says french date format is dd-mm-yyyy ( with dd = 2 digit day, mm = two digit month and yyyy = 4 digit year) and it states the ISO Norm as "NF EN 28601" - so I second the voices that your customer actually wants something *very* odd. (I will not make a statement about the french, now ;) haha )

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you need a date in a language-specific format, you should pass the appropriate `CultureInfo` to `ToString`:

```
.ToString(..., CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

Furthermore, this is ambiguous *and* not a standard format, so the easiest way is to just use a lookup table for the months and construct the string yourself.

Comment: The lookup would be easy - just a `string[12]` with the month abbreviations. `date.Month-1` could be used as an index

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can guess, you want kind of *Canadian* abbreviation:

http://interglacial.com/pub/text/Canadian_month_abbreviations.html

which is English/French names compromise

> The reason that the abbreviations are a little odd at points is that
>   they're based on a compromise between the full English month names and
>   the full French month names

If it's your case, I suggest using *custom* DateTime Format:

```
   // fr-FR - France (The customer is from [Mainland?] France)
   // fr-CA - Canada (Origin of the abbreviations)
   DateTimeFormatInfo caFormat = 
     (DateTimeFormatInfo) (CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR").DateTimeFormat.Clone());

   caFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames = new string[] { 
     "JA", "FE", "MR", "AL", "MA", "JN", "JL", "AU", "SE", "OC", "NO", "DE", "" };
```

Using

```
   DateTime value = new DateTime(2016, 3, 1);  

   // Formatting as usual but with custom format
   String result = value.ToString("ddMMMyyyy", caFormat);
```

Outcome

```
   01MR2016
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are refering to a Canadian standard, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_and_time_notation_in_Canada)
.Net does not provide that conversion,but you can do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> abbr = new Dictionary<string, string>() {    
                                                                    {"Jan","JA"},
                                                                    { "Feb","FE"},
                                                                    { "Mar","MR"},
                                                                    { "Apr","AL"},
                                                                    { "May","MA"},
                                                                    { "Jun","JN"},
                                                                    { "Jul","JL"},
                                                                    { "Aug","AU"},
                                                                    { "Sep","SE"},
                                                                    { "Oct","OC"},
                                                                    { "Nov","NO"},
                                                                    { "Dec","DE"}

            };
string val = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).ToString("ddMMMyyyy",
                                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var newstr = abbr.Aggregate(val, (current, value) =>
 current.Replace(value.Key, value.Value));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
value = Convert.ToDateTime(currentDate).ToString("ddMMyyyy",new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

Comment: `MM` doesn't mean "two letter month" - it means "two *digit* month".

Answer (score -1):

I don't think so that its having any solution but yeah you can try `split()` function and by splitting date after `2 digits of day + two letters of month` and again merge the string, hope that will help you.

Comment: What `Split` function? DateTime doesn't have a split function and the string doesn't have any separators. Retrieving the date elements from the date value itself is as easy as calling `date.Month`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think they mean `Substring`

Comment: @TheLethalCoder string manipulation is a bad idea when you can get the month directly from the date object

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I know and that is what it isn't my idea